# Kendo MVC ComboBox Highlight Content

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, combobox, telerik-mvc

On document.ready I would like to set the state of the combobox so the content is highlighted and filtering is ready so the user just has to start typing without further input with the mouse. This is the cb:

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
    .Name("cboLocations")
    .Filter("contains")
    .Suggest(true)
    .BindTo(Model.Locations)
    .DataTextField("Text")
    .DataValueField("Value")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
)
```

I'd like it to look like:

[image]

after the document.ready(); so the user just has to start typing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually stumbled across it:

```
combobox.input.select();
```

http://www.telerik.com/forums/selecting-kendocombobox-text

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the focus event?

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var combobox = $("#cboLocations").data("kendoComboBox");
        combobox.focus();
    });

</script>
```

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/combobox#methods-focus

Comment: Yes, that only places the cursor at the end of the text.